# Dockerfile entrypoint/cmd not executing on container import

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to export a container, import it and then run it. But, the `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` in dockerfile is not executing on the imported container.

How do I execute the same commands specified in Dockerfile when the image was built? I know that it can be specified with `docker run image <cmd>` but, how is the `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` lost in the export/import process? And, is there a better way for importing/exporting containers?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

WORKDIR app

ADD ./app.py .
ADD ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

And the commands run in succession:

```sh
docker build . -t python-app
docker run --name app-container python-app    
docker export app-container > app-container.tar  
docker import app-container.tar "import-container:latest"  
docker run --name import import-container:latest    
# docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to "export a container" at all.  Normal use is to `docker run` new containers based on the image that Dockerfile builds.  This is the same way, without Docker, you'd run new processes based on that `app.py` script and not try to take snapshots of the running application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker export` exports the filesystem of a container, not an image. That's why the CMD and ENTRYPOINT aren't exported.

If you want to make a tar file from an image, you should use `docker save` and `docker load` rather than `docker export` and `docker import`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `docker import` you need to do:

```
docker import --change 'CMD ["python3", "app.py"]' image_archive.tar)
```